# Typing accents (diacritics) in a Google Docs document, using Google Chrome in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: google-chrome, google-docs, diacritics

On the other hand, I can do it everywhere: the address bar, in a Google Spreadsheet... even in a Google Docs document using Mozilla Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I am having this same problem since Version 53.0.2785.101 (64-bit). It works on every site, except Google docs products. On a spreadsheet it only works if I type on the formula bar. If I type on any cell it doesn't.

So I found others are having the same issue [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/N_QVGXPP0Gw). Reverting back to version 52 solved the issue for me, so it is for sure an issue with version 53. I reported the issue to Google Chrome and I suggest you do the same.